# php, mysql - delete item from dropdown and database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ***dropdown menu***. I want to ***delete*** a selected ***item*** from the ***dropdown and*** the ***database***.

For clarity, I outsourced the database connection instructions and call them in the necessary places with - require ("db.inc.php");.

I have written a class and method to delete the selected article (a variable). I call the method in the file - testdelete.php. And via a button in the index file.

There must, however, be an error in the transfer of the variables. I think the passage with the form is grotty. - I can use the script to delete an article, but not the one currently selected.

Does anyone have an idea or solution?
That would be great

***The Index-File:***

```
<!-- class, function -->
<?php
class artikel {
    private $table = "artikel";

    public function delete_a($id) {
   // connection to the db
require("db.inc.php");
//
 $sql = "DELETE FROM " .$this->table ." WHERE anr = ?";
 if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt -> execute();
  }
  $stmt->close();
  $mysqli->close(); 
}
}
?>
<!-- -->
<?php 
// connection to the database
require("db.inc.php");
// SQL command
$sql = "SELECT anr, name FROM artikel";
// prepared Statements
    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql)) 
        { 
            $stmt -> execute(); 
            $stmt -> bind_result($anr, $name); 
?>
<!--form, select and option -->
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label for="artikel">Artikel</label>
            <select id="artikel" name="artikel">

<?php
            while ($stmt -> fetch()) 
            {
                echo "<option value=\"\">"
                    . $anr 
                    . "|" 
                    . $name
                    . "</option>\n\t";
            }
?>
            </select>
            <p>
                  <a href="testdelete.php?anr=<?php echo $anr; ?>">
                  <input type="button" value="Delete article"></a>
                  </p>
       </form>
<?php                  
            $stmt->close(); 
        } 
        $mysqli->close();   
?>
```

***Connection to the db (db.inc.php)***

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxx", "myDB");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  echo "You see an error: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  exit();
}
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
  echo "UTF8 don't work: ". $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

And the function call delete in a external file named testdelete.php:

```
<?php 
// function call
    if(isset($_GET["anr"])) {
    $artikel = new artikel();
    $artikel -> delete_a($_GET["anr"]);
    echo "<h2>Article deleted</h2>";
    }
    header("refresh:3; url=index.php");
?>
```

Comment: i am unable to understand what your problem is?

Comment: I can use the script to delete an article, but not the one currently selected.

Comment: Oh, you are a profi. - I am a beginner.

Comment: The problem is - I mean - the transfer of the variables in the form.

Comment: You have to use a post request if you want to perform a delete action in your database

Comment: you are posting the select menu after selecting a value and your select dropdown name is artikle where as in your script you are getting $_GET['anr']

Comment: does your form submits when you click the button

Comment: yes, it works. it delete an item and gives an 3 seconds commend, that this was succsessfull.

Comment: but it is not the selected item

Comment: It doesn't delete your selected item because your '$anr' is empty in <a href="testdelete.php?anr=<?php echo $anr; ?>">

Comment: I am afraid, it is not enough to change the 'id' ore the 'name' of the <selec> in 'anr' ... ' - instead of 'artikel'.

Comment: @Jerome why and what can I do?

Comment: The answer of @YouneL is good, your `$anr`variable is undefined, it's only exist on your while loop, and your  `a href="testdelete.php?anr=<?php echo $anr; ?>` will not never modified, you're code couldn't work, do a post is a good choice.

Comment: Sorry I was tired. And I can't get the code run. You are right. I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Defining classes was not necessary for this little script. This works (adapted to database information and the name of the php file).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// function for dropdown, select
function dataSelect($db) {
    $dropdown = "<select name=\"anr\" id=\"anr\">\n"; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM article"; 
    if ($stmt = $db -> prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt -> execute();
        if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {    
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                $dropdown .= "<option value=\"".$row->anr."\"\n"; 
                $dropdown .= ">" .$row->anr." | " .$row->name." </option>"; 
            }
        }
    }       
    else    {
        return false;
    }
    $dropdown .= "</select>\n";
    return $dropdown; 
}
// \ 

// try DB
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "examplDB");
if ($db->connect_error) {
    echo "Error: ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}
if (!$db->set_charset("utf8")) { 
echo "Error -> UTF8 ". $mysqli->error;
}
// \ 

// form
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">
      <label for=\"anr\">Article: </label>\n";
echo dataSelect($db); // select
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Data delete\"     />\n"; 
echo "</form>";
// \ 

// delete Data
if (isset($_POST['Delete']))        {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM article WHERE anr = ?"; 
    if ($stmt = $db -> prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['anr']);
        $stmt -> execute();
    }
    echo "<h1>Data deleted</h1>";
    header("refresh:3;url=_self_");
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli -> close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To use post request instead, and you have to pass an action to your form, try this code:

**The Index-File:**

```
<?php 
// connection to the database
require("db.inc.php");
// SQL command
$sql = "SELECT anr, name FROM artikel";
// prepared Statements
    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql)) 
        { 
            $stmt -> execute(); 
            $stmt -> bind_result($anr, $name); 
?>
<!--form, select and option -->
        <form action="testdelete.php" method="POST"> 
            <label for="artikel">Artikel</label>
            <select id="artikel" name="artikel">

<?php
            while ($stmt -> fetch()) 
            {
                // here you have to pass a value to your select
                echo "<option value=\"$anr\">"
                    . $anr 
                    . "|" 
                    . $name
                    . "</option>\n\t";
            }
?>
            </select>
            <p>
                <!-- here you have to use submit button in order to post your selected value -->
                <input type="submit" value="Delete article">
            </p>
    </form>
<?php                  
            $stmt->close(); 
        } 
        $mysqli->close();   
?>
```

**testdelete.php**

```
<?php 
// function call
    if(isset($_post["artikel"])) { // that's because your select name is "arikel"
    $artikel = new artikel();
    $artikel -> delete_a($_post["artikel"]);
    echo "<h2>Article deleted</h2>";
    }
    header("refresh:3; url=index.php");
?>
```

Comment: No idea, how to insert the value to these option passage.

Comment: I commented the code above try to read it and adapt it to your situation

Comment: No, I do not see the forest for the trees. - I've been looking at the computer for too long.

Comment: I'm at the end. The battery is empty. I will try again tomorrow. - Thank you for the help.

Comment: @fl1tz, Did you find where the problem come from or not?

Comment: I can't realise it.

Comment: If I have a solution, I'll post it Herr.